# Whats the equivalent of data_color from gt package in kable?

Tags: r, kable, gt

I am trying to do this table in `kable` package:

[image]

To do this, I am using `data_color` function from `gt` package.

I would like to know if there is any option to do the same in `kable` package.

My code:

```
tbl_ipca %>%
      gt() %>%
      data_color(
            columns = 1:3,
            colors = scales::col_numeric(
                  colorspace::diverge_hcl(n = 20, palette = "Blue-Red 3"),
                  reverse = FALSE,
                  domain = c(-max(abs(tbl_ipca[1:3])), max(abs(tbl_ipca[1:3])))
            )
      ) %>%
      data_color(
            columns = 4:6,
            colors = scales::col_numeric(
                  colorspace::diverge_hcl(n = 20, palette = "Blue-Red 3"),
                  reverse = FALSE,
                  domain = c(-max(abs(tbl_ipca[4:6])), max(abs(tbl_ipca[4:6])))
            )
      ) %>%
      data_color(
            columns = 7:9,
            colors = scales::col_numeric(
                  colorspace::diverge_hcl(n = 20, palette = "Blue-Red 3"),
                  reverse = FALSE,
                  domain = c(-max(abs(tbl_ipca[7:9])), max(abs(tbl_ipca[7:9])))
            )
      ) %>%
      data_color(
            columns = 10:12,
            colors = scales::col_numeric(
                  colorspace::diverge_hcl(n = 20, palette = "Blue-Red 3"),
                  reverse = FALSE,
                  domain = c(-max(abs(tbl_ipca[10:12])), max(abs(tbl_ipca[10:12])))
            )
      )
```

My `dput()`:

```
structure(list(`Set/21` = c(1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 0.9, 1.9, 0.7, 1.3, 
0.3, 0.6), `Out/21` = c(1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.2, 1.4, 1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 
1), `Nov/21` = c(0.6, 1.7, 0.9, 0.4, 2.3, 0.3, 0, 1, 0.3), `Set/21` = c(2.8, 
3.5, 3, 2.4, 4.6, 2.2, 3.2, 2.1, 1.7), `Out/21` = c(3.4, 3.9, 
3.3, 3, 4.3, 2.6, 3.9, 2.9, 2.1), `Nov/21` = c(2.9, 4.2, 3.4, 
2.6, 5.7, 2.3, 2.6, 2.9, 2), `Set/21` = c(5.1, 5.9, 4.8, 3.6, 
8.1, 2.4, 5, 4.6, 1.8), `Out/21` = c(5.9, 6.5, 5.7, 4.5, 9.2, 
3.5, 6, 5.7, 2.8), `Nov/21` = c(5.5, 7.2, 5.9, 4.6, 9.4, 4, 5.2, 
5.8, 3.3), `Set/21` = c(12.5, 11, 10.2, 8.4, 15.7, 5.4, 13.9, 
7.8, 4.4), `Out/21` = c(12, 11.5, 10.7, 8.5, 17, 6, 13.1, 8.4, 
4.9), `Nov/21` = c(10.8, 12.4, 10.7, 7.8, 19.2, 5.7, 10.4, 9.2, 
4.8)), row.names = c("Comercializáveis", "Duráveis", "IPCA", 
"Livres", "Monitorados", "Não Comercializáveis", "Não Duráveis", 
"Semi-Duráveis", "Serviços"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Header_Rows

Comment: Yes, but the conditional present there is to specify a value, like `ifelse(x > 10, red, green)`. In `data_color` I just specify the range and then it applies the colors.

Comment: If you provide your data, perhaps the community can better support you. Create a dataframe of the tbl_ipca object for our use and place it in the post by editing. You could use the dput() function.

Comment: I just added. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Something seems a bit off because you have duplicate column names....

Comment: Yes, but I need to be the same. That’s why I would like to use `kable` instead of `gt`.